# SQL: Best way to conditionally relate multiple tables to a single table based on row value in the main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

In a nutshell here's the situation, we have a database that is used to build a hierarchy of "locations". (Example: Street Address > Building 1 > First Floor > Room).

Each of the locations are stored in a table.  Each location can be of a different "type".  The types are defined in another table.  (We use the types of locations to restrict what locations can be added to a location).

Here's the quandary we are facing:  We need to be able to store different types of information for different types of locations.  For example, a location type of "building" may need to have the address stored where as a location type of "room" may need to have dimensions or paint color stored.

Obviously we could create a table for each location type we define to hold the properties required for the particular location type and then use application logic to query the appropriate table to pull in a particular location's additional information.  Is there a more elegant or practical way to accomplish this relationally in the database without having to rely on application logic?

Thanks!

Comment: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question599.htm or maybe http://www.amazon.co.uk/SQL-For-Dummies-Computers/dp/0470557419 would be good places to start

Comment: Thanks for the information but we're fine with SQL basics and such.  I've updated the opening post to hopefully be a little more clear on what the actual quandary is.

Comment: Creating a table for each location type can get bulky and difficult to maintain...you'll have headaches later on.  EAV models will support what you want...maybe give sparse columns in mssql a read too

Comment: Thanks, Twelfth.  I was looking into using an EAV model a bit earlier.  I'll dig into that a bit more and take a deeper look at sparse columns as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationally pure way to do this would be to implement your initial suggestion i.e. have a separate table such as BUILDING_LOCATIONS that holds the attributes that are only applicable to this type of location. A different [TYPE]_LOCATIONS table would be created for each type of location that has its own attributes. In this way you could use standard database constraint functionality to ensure the integrity of the data in these tables.

Another method would be to add a series of nullable columns to the LOCATIONS table such as BUILDING_ADDRESS and ROOM_DIMENSIONS. This is not relationally pure as it means null values can exist in this table. However, you can still use standard database functionality to ensure the integrity of the data. It can be a bit more convoluted if certain values are mandatory in certain situations. Also, if there are many types of location with many differing attributes the number of columns in the table can become unwieldy.

Another method is the Entity-Attribute-Value model. Generally, this is to be avoided if at all possible. It is not relationally pure, as your column values are now no longer defined over domains, and it is extremely difficult, if not impossible, to ensure the integrity of the data. Any real attempt to do so will require a lot of bespoke coding (which needs to be carefully implemented to cater for things like concurrency control that database constraints give you for free) as you cannot use standard database constraints. However, if you are just interested in storing values for information and not doing anything with them you could use this method.

The EAV method does have a danger that because it appears so easy to add attributes to an entity, it becomes the default way of doing so. It is then used to add attributes for which vital processing is dependent and, because you cannot ensure the integrity of the data using this method, you find the values being used are meaningless and the whole logical basis for the processing is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, DrabJay.  Doing some more digging into EAV, I don't think that is something we want to implement in part due to the short falls that you mentioned.  As of right now, I think we'll go with the [TYPE]_LOCATIONS idea and see how that plays out in our tests.  Thanks again!